# How to re-encrypt the private key of a certificate in AES?

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

Tried to read the private key (test.key.pem) of the certificate

str = private key without -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----

```
byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(str);
EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo epk = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(bytes);
```

But I'm getting an error

```
PBE parameter parsing error: expecting the object identifier for AES cipher
```

After I experienced making rsa aes certificate in openssl:

```
rsa -aes-256-cbc -in Z:\40000214_test.key -out Z:\file.txt.enc
```

But I catch completely different errors.
For example this:

```
java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=5, too big.
```

also instead of "rsa" command I used "enc" and the result was also erroneous

as a result, I was able to achieve re-encryption of the private key. openssl

```
pkcs8 -v1 PBE-SHA1-3DES -topk8 -in so_privatekey_secret.pem -out so_privatekey_3des_secret.pem
```

But the problems did not leave me and when sending the request I received the following exception

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The certificate is expired there, but requests go through postman and also with a new private key
I disabled all certificate checks in Java Control Panel but it didn't help, I also imported the certificate into jvm